# How to send multiple values to mysql tables in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, foreach

I'm new to PHP and Yii framework. how to insert multiple questions in database

This is Form view code

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'questions',array('id'=>"content_#index#_question textBox")); ?>

<?php echo $form->textField($model,'questions',array('id'=>"content_#index#_question textBox")); ?>
```

Here is My Controller

```
public function actionAdd_quick()

{

    $model=new Question;
    $answers=new Answers;

    if(isset($_POST['Question'],$_POST['Answers']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Question'];
        $answers->attributes=$_POST['Answers'];
                foreach ($model['questions'] as $value) {
                    $model->questions = $value;

                }
                $model->save();

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('add_quick','Thank you for ');
            $this->refresh();

    }
    $this->render('add_quick',array('model'=>$model,'answers'=>$answers));
}
```

actually my process is to create multiple questions and answers ,but now getting error like

"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" by using my code and how to send multiple questions and answers to mysql tables...

Comment: What you want to do ? Insert multiple answers to a question. Or insert question and answer pairs

Comment: i have to insert both multiple Questions and answers,but here i mentioned only for question

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
foreach ($model['questions'] as $value) {
                $model->questions = $value;

            }
            $model->save();
```

on this

```
foreach ($model['questions'] as $value) {
                $model->questions = $value;
                $model->save();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'questions[]',array('id'=>"content_#index#_question textBox"));  ?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response,i did change as you said but now single row only inserted...